# Get db connection mvc php out of contorller class in php

Tags: php, scope, static-methods

Here this is the code for connecting to database. At last I have a new function to **select** **options**, but I need db connection

For example I put **$connertion**

**new edit**

This code has an error

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in F:\xampp\htdocs\wantons\application\core\controller.php on line 19

```
class Controller{

    function __construct() {
        $this->openDatabaseConnection();
        $this->loadModel();
    }

    private function openDatabaseConnection() {
        $options = array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
        $this->db = new PDO(DB_TYPE . ':host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';charset=' . DB_CHARSET, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $options);
    }

    public function DB(){
        return $this->db; // -> line 19
    }

    public function loadModel(){
        require APP . 'model/model.php';
        $this->model = new Model($this->db);
    }
}
```

And the function **Out of Class**

```
function get_option($name) {

    $db = Controller::DB();
    $query = $db->query("SELECT `option_value` FROM ".PREFIX."options where `option_name` = '$name' ");

    // we need top codes !
    $query->execute();
    $fetchAll = $query->fetchAll();
    echo $fetchAll[0]['option_value']; 
}
```

Comment: you can use a singleton static function, [sample](https://gist.github.com/rob-murray/5454707)

Comment: how is your mvc structure, can you explain more specifically?

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/panique/mini

Comment: i put a new function `DB` but has error

Comment: `this->db` have to be declared like an attribute according the error

Comment: like this `class Controller{ private $db;private $model; ...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85136/discussion-between-miglio-and-danial-dezfooli).

Comment: and function get_option($name) , where is located?

Comment: in functions.php (it's `require` in config.php)